# Cannot send email using mailgun or mailer

Tags: flutter, mailgun, mailer

I tried to use this amazing plugin to send an email.

https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer#sending-an-email-with-smtp

I also created my mailgun account to be used as my personal username and password to use the mailer data. In fact, I can login to mailgun.com using this account. Unfortunately, I kept getting an error like this.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Socket was closed even though a response was expected.

or

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Incorrect username / password

This is for allowing the user to send an email without opening other application such as gmail app. I've tried different methods in my code but no luck. :(

```
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server/mailgun.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';

Future<void> mailGun() async {
    String username = 'my-email';
    String password = 'my-password';


    final smtpServer = mailgun(username, password);

    // and even using this method.

    // final smtpServer = new SmtpServer('smtp.mailgun.org',
    //username: username, password: password, port: 587, ssl: false);

    final message = new Message()
      ..from = new Address(username, 'Your_name')
      ..recipients.add('sample@email.com')
      ..subject = 'Subject'
      ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the 
text part.'
      ..html = "<h1>test</p>";

    print('tosend');
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer, 
catchExceptions: false);
    print('sended');
    return sendReport;
}
```

I expect that the code should automatically send an email to the designated recipient without using any third party app.

Edit:

Hi all, I am able to solve this using this code;

```
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server/gmail.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';

Future<void> _sendEmail() async {
    String username = 'sample';
    String password = 'sample@123';

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

    final message = new Message()
      ..from = new Address("sample@gmail.com", 'sample@123')
      ..recipients.add(_email)
      ..subject = 'Mobile Verification App'
      ..html = """
                <h3>You are now registered</h3>
                <p>Name: $toCamelCaseFName $toCamelCaseLName</p>
                <p>organization: $_organization</p>
                <p>pin: $orgId</p>
              """;

    final sendReport = send(message, smtpServer, catchExceptions: false);
    return sendReport;
  }
```

This code used gmail as an example.

Comment: Are you sure about your Mailun credentials?

Comment: Any update about it?

Comment: Hi @ZeffryReynando, I just updated the code that I used to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your mailgun account requires two-factor authentification which is [not supported by mailer package](https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/issues/80). 
To solve this problem, you can [create additional SMTP credentials](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203409084-How-Do-I-Create-Additional-SMTP-Credentials-) specifically for your app.